# Sympy patterns for functions

Tags: python, design-patterns, wolfram-mathematica, sympy

In Wolfram Research Mathematica it is possible to define a sustitution rule of the type

```
sustitution = g_[arg___] -> g[Sequence @@ Reverse[{arg}]]
```

Then it is possible to apply it to different expressions involving functions with the following results:

```
f[x, y] /. sustitution   >>  f[y,x]
g[x1,x2,x3]              >>  g[x3,x2,x1]
h[1,z,w,t]/.sustitution  >>  h[t,w,z,1]
```

As it is possible to use a pattern with name, g_, for the name of the function and another pattern, arg___, for the arguments, the same sustitution rule is valid no matter the name of the function that appears in the expression.

Is it possible to use WildFunction symbols along with replace to obtain a similar efect with Sympy?

Answer (score 2):

The `arg__` is not necessary for a SymPy type arg-remapping function since the args can be retrieved from the function call itself:

```
>>> from sympy.abc import x,y,z
>>> from sympy import Function
>>> f = Function('f')
>>> g_ = lambda f: f.func(*list(reversed(f.args)))
>>> g_(f(x,y,z))
f(z, y, x)
```

Another way of changing all user-defined functions the same way within an expression is to use `replace` as follows:

```
>>> from sympy.abc import *
>>> from sympy import Function, AppliedUndef
>>> f,g,h,F=symbols('f,g,h,F',cls=Function)
>>> eq=f(x,y,z)+g(y,x,w)*h(1,u,t)**cos(F(x,y,1,w))
>>> eq.replace(
... lambda x: isinstance(x, AppliedUndef),
... lambda x: x.func(*list(reversed(x.args))))
f(z, y, x) + g(w, x, y)*h(t, u, 1)**cos(F(w, 1, y, x))
```

If you wanted to apply such a transformation to *all* functions then use `Function` instead of `AppliedUndef`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @smichr but I was thinking in applying the substitution in more difficult expression as `code`f(x,y,z)+g(y,x,w)*h(1,g,t)**cos(F(x,y,1,w))`code` or so. For this reason I was thinking in using replace and WildFunction symbols. My goal is to understand better how to control the attirbutes of sympy functions symbols by means of WildFunction symbols and whether it is possible to reproduce the pattern Mathematica style with them.

Comment: Dear @smichr, I thought about this other solution:`code` F=WildFunction("F")`code` `code` (f(x,y)+g(x,y,z)).replace(F , lambda F:F.func(*list(reversed(F.args))))`code`. I wondered why it was not possible to access the information of a WildFunction symbol and, inspired on your answer I tried this. I see that if you try F.func or F.args without using lambda, you obtain a mistake message. Bests.