# Sympy function reverse

Tags: python, sympy

I am very new to `sympy` and I'm trying to figure out how to reverse a function.

I have a function `g(x, y)` where the types of `x` and `y` is `sympy` `symbol`. I want to reverse this like below:

```
   .--.
   |  v
 g(x, y) -> g(y, x)
   ^  |
   `--'
```

Is there any way to do this?

For example:

```py
symbol = Function(l_expr)(*tuple(r_expr.free_symbols))
```

For this case, `symbol` is coming as `g(x, y)`. Here `x` is the default parameter, and `y` is the non-default parameter.

The requirement is if `x` comes first and then `y` then reverse the symbols.

```py
if symbol.args[0] != r_expr.args[0]:
    # do something which will reverse the symbols
```

Comment: I don't understand. Just write `g(y, x)`!?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I can't hardcode that. Is there any way to do that using any builtin method ex: transpose or reverse?

Comment: It depends... can you please show a more concrete example?

Comment: @mkrieger1 basically for my usecase based on certain condition I want to reverse the symbols.lets say default a=g(x,y). If a condition is met then I want to get a=g(y,x)

Comment: Yes. Can you please show a more concrete example where it becomes clear that you cannot simply write `g(y, x)`? ([edit] your question to add this information)

Comment: @mkrieger1 can you please check?

Comment: I've never used sympy, but maybe `symbol.args = symbol.args[::-1]` should work in your `if` branch

Comment: it's giving `AttributeError: can't set attribute`

Comment: `if ...: (x,y) = (y,x)`

Comment: You can use replace: `g(x, y).replace(g, lambda x, y: g(y, x))`

Comment: Yes, this can be done. It is discussed in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66993422/1089161).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the function and want to reverse the args:

```
>>> g(x,y)
g(x, y)
>>> _.func(*_.args[::-1])
g(y, x)
```

If you need to hunt the functions down in an expression then my link to the other answer (which directs you to use `replace`) will be helpful.